# SQL select all that is outside of the parentheses

Tags: sql, substring

I have a bunch of lines in my database that look something like this:

```
123 'text i want (textidontwant)'
```

and I'm trying to select everything from the database with the text i want only.

I know that I'm supposed to use substring, but I'm not sure how to.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Work a litle more in provide a better example. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: this highly depends on what kind of database you are using, but typically, if you can guarantee the first open parenthesis is the delimiter for what you don't want, you can do a substring(field, 0, <whatever your database's function is to get first occurance of a character>('(') )

Comment: If you already know that you should use `substring` and you see in the docs that it has three parameters; the column, the start, and the end or length; then you know you need `substring(col, 1, ___)` already. So all you need to find out is how to locate the parenthesis. I don't understand why you can't find this in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use substr and locate or charindex

in mysql

```
select substr(my_column, 1, locate('(', my_column))
from my_table
```

in sqlserver

```
select substring(my_column, 1, charindex('(', my_column)) 
from my_table
```

Comment: `select substring(my_column, 1, charindex('(', my_column))
from my_table ` for SQL Server

Comment: @PirateX  thanks  .. i have update the answer but you should post your comment like an answer so can be rated  properly

Comment: I wasn't sure if it's worth another answer. Better to update yours. Will take care next time.

Comment: If you posted the answer i rate it .

Answer (score 0):

```
select ... where column_name like '%text that I want%' and column_name not like '%text that I do not want%'
```

Assuming that substring matches are OK (`%` is wildcard, at least in PostgreSQL)

**EDIT:** it seems I misunderstood the question, but I'll leave the answer here in case it helps someone the way it is... :)

Comment: This will still return the complete string. The "%" sign is used to define wildcards (missing letters) both before and after the pattern.

Comment: Aah, then I misunderstood - I thought he wanted all rows that contained the one part but not the other, not that he wanted the actual substring...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
LEFT(column, CHARINDEX('(', column) - 1)
```

This will get the left part of a string in column **column**, ending at one character before the index of the first **open parentheses (**.

So,

```
123 'text i want (textidontwant)'
```

will become

```
123 'text i want '
```

Notice that the trailing space will remain!!! To remove trailing space, use **RTRIM** like so:

```
RTRIM(LEFT(column, CHARINDEX('(', column) - 1))
```

(**CHARINDEX** is T-SQL only, if you need a different version of SQL please edit your tags.)